# ValidationResult throws : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". when passing back choices

Tags: bots, botframework

Please find the below exception.

> Stack Trace: Exception: Exception caught:
>   'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormCanceledException1' in
>   mscorlib.dll ("Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."). Exception caught:
>   'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormCanceledException1' in
>   mscorlib.dll ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.")

Hi, I am trying to generate form flow and during validation, If user enters wrong text then I am passing choices to select from but bot however throws above exception and emulator hangs.

Below is the example

```C#
.Field(nameof(RegistrationForm.ModelNumber), validate: async (state, value) =>
{
var modelsSuggestion = PimsServiceClient.GetModelSuggestion();
ValidateResult validateResult = new ValidateResult()
{
IsValid = modelsSuggestion.Any(m => m.ToLower().Equals(value?.ToString().ToLower())),
Value = value,
Choices = new List(modelsSuggestion.Select(s => new Choice { Value = s } }))
};

 /* Do some database stuff */
  return validateResult;
 })
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace for the NullReferenceException?

Comment: Do you know the values of "value" and of the elements of your choices?  Are any of them null?

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and figred out that i had to provide all the property values for choices like below

```
 var choices = new List<Choice>();

choices.Add(new Choice { Description = new DescribeAttribute("Tes1", null, "Tes1", null, null), Value ="Tes1", Terms = new TermsAttribute("Tes1", "T1")});

choices.Add(new Choice { Description = new DescribeAttribute("Test2", null, "Test2", null, null), Value = "Test2", Terms = new TermsAttribute("Test2", "T2") });

    ValidateResult validateResult = new ValidateResult()
                {
                /*if modelSuggestion != null && modelsSuggestion.Any()*/
                IsValid = false,
                Value = value,
                Choices = choices
            };
```